# How to use post method via MVC

Tags: php, post, model-view-controller, zend-framework

This is my view file called `application.html`.

I just started learning the Zend framework.

I have existing database table (`mytable.sql`), with three columns:

- `ID`
- `APP_ID`
- `APP_NAME`

So now my goal is, I need create new app using post method and that new app name must be save in to database.

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/appmgt/createAction">
    <p>
        <label class="field" for="APP_ID"><span>*</span>APP_ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="APP_ID" class="textbox-300" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="field" for="APP_NAME"><span>*</span>APP_NAME</label>
        <input type="text" name="APP_NAME" class="textbox-300" />
    </p>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Form' />
</form>
```

This my controller file:

```
public function createAction() {    
    $this->view->form = $this->getForm();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if (!$this->view->form->isValid($_POST)) {
            return $this->render('form');
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Model file:

```
public function createApp($APP_ID, $APP_NAME) {
    $data = array(
        'APP_ID'   => $APP_ID,
        'APP_NAME' => $$APP_NAME
    );
    $this->insert($data);
}
```

Could you please help me ?

Comment: What kind of framework are you using?

Comment: Hi David, I am using zendframe work.

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: when i am clicking submit button, i get the error "An error occurred
Page not found"

Comment: make sure you can open the url /admin/appmgt/createAction in the browser.
You might have to correct the routes.